# Ngninx deny access by IP to Get request

Tags: nginx

I have an application  that has an admin panel called domain.com/agent/ but there is no direct path in the server's root directory to block. I can see  the log, there is a GET request to /agent/
I want to restrict by IP the access to /agent/ and /agent/login/

As of know, these examples are not helpful:

```
location ~ /agent/ {

        allow 1.1.1.1;
        allow 1.2.3.4;
        deny all;
 }
```

---

```
location ^~ /agent/ {

        allow 1.1.1.1;
        allow 1.2.3.4;
        deny all;
 }
```

What does this is to block all access to /agent/ and is not taking in consideration the allow list.

Comment: Are you sure that you are trying from an IP address that is allowed?

Comment: yes, it has giving me 404 error. I also tried denying IP first and allowing everything else but the same result.

Comment: @JOR17: `404` means `Page not found`, if you are blocked by the `allow`/`deny` rules you should get a `403`.

Comment: Please submit your url u use i would suggest to move deny all to the first and after that the allow line, however i think either the host is not regionized you try i. E. You use ServerName hostname but try with ip this would not Match, moreover Post nginx/apache2ctl - S

Comment: @djdomi What's the use of knowing the URL in this use-case, where all access is blocked?

Comment: Sorry the error is not 404. The error is 403 Forbidden. The url is https://sub.example.com/agent/. In the logs I can see [error] 27616#0: * access forbidden by rule, client:xxx.xxx.xxx, server: _,: “GET /agent /HTTP/1.1”, host “sub.example.com

Comment: Please add exact copies from your log files into the question by editing the question. The line above is not from nginx server log, since the slash is in wrong place.